# python curve_fit to a single data point

Tags: python, curve-fitting

Using curve_fit, how do I fit a curve, which has only one free parameter to a single data point?

Say I want to fit a function: f(x,a)=12.3x^2+a to a point (2,3).

What I get is just an error, since a single data point has no length:

' ysize = len(infodict['fvec'])
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()'

Thanks,

Mac

Tried fitting with curve_fit but failed, got an above error.

Comment: you need to provide a working code example that shows the error. and include the error traceback in the question.

Comment: We need to see your implementation and how you defined your function's return, especially its type.

Comment: a single float has no length, but nothing stops you from creating an array with length 1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing arrays rather than individual values:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
>>> popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda x, a: 12.3 * x**2 + a, np.array([2]), np.array([3]))
/home/runner/HeartfeltLovingCodegeneration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py:1010: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated',
>>> popt[0]
-46.2
```

OptimizeWarning is because you are trying to fit a single point...